# Android Studio: Error getting string from resource in multi-language app

Tags: android, multilingual, android-resources

I have a classic multi-language setup in my app with two 'values' folders: `values` for default danish language and `values-se` for swedish. My device is set to locale `sw-SE`, but my app still shows string resources in danish (default).
If I move the danish resources to a folder `values-da` (for danish) and create an empty folder `values`, Then I get the error that the resource is not found. I this case if finds nither danish nor swedish strings.

Here is a typical call to a resource:

```
m_ButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = m_EditEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass = m_EditPassword.getText().toString();

        if (email.equals("") == false && pass.equals("") == false) {
            //Save user info to Crashlytics
            Crashlytics.setUserEmail(email);

            showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.wait), getResources().getString(R.string.logging_on));

            Intent logOnIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), dk.le34.taskassistant.activity.TaskAssistantService.class);
            logOnIntent.addCategory("dk.le34.taskassistant.LOG_ON");
            logOnIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", email);
            logOnIntent.putExtra("PASSWORD", pass);
            logOnIntent.putExtra("REMEMBER", m_CheckBoxRemember.isChecked());
            startService(logOnIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.user_details), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

My setup is by the book, so why do I get these errors?

Comment: It seems your locale doesn't match values-se. Check again.

Comment: I changed the locale to sw-SE. I could see in the logcat that this has been done correctly, and the device language is in swedish all arround. Tried it on a Genymotion emulator and the result is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, Language files not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501801/android-language-files-not-work)

Comment: a little research before posting a question please.

Comment: Excuse my rudeness, but i did that, and I didn't find this duplicate. If you don't want to help, stay off the thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale for Swedish is "sv_SE". Your Swedish resources need to go into `values-sv`, not `values-se`.

"sv" is the language (in this case Swedish)
"SE" is the country (in this case Sweden)